# Is it possible to refactor this function's code architecture with break statement?

Tags: python

I have to refactor a code in python that uses this architecture :

```
def f():
    def g1():
        -code-
    g1()

    def g2():
       -code-

    g2()

   def g3():
       -code-

   g3()
```

My function `f()` is called by a Tkinter button. Is this architecture OK and efficient or should I remove nested functions?

How to break function after `g1()` to avoid execution of `g2()` and `g3()` without using `if/else` statements and not repeat myself too much?

Comment: What's the condition for returning before you call `g2` or `g3`?

Comment: Do you just want `for g in [g1,g2,g3]: if g(): return`?

Comment: `break` is for terminating loops. To exit from a function, use a `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid execution, you must return rather than break.
Break is for looping constructs.

Also check out yield and generator logic in python, which can start your function execution from where you left off the first time when you call it back!

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-yield-stmt